# Python Panda Bloomberg xbbg Request time

Tags: python, pandas, bloomberg

I am requesting data from a large dataframe through xbbg but a lot of the fields are coming back as NaN when the data is actually available on Bloomberg. I suspect that the values are returning null because Bloomberg takes time to update all values and was wondering if there is a way to allow for a longer response time from BBG before the data is returned.

This is an example of the data request:

```
u=blp.bdp(x['cusip'],\
flds=['INTERVAL_PERCENT_CHANGE', 'TICKER_AND_EXCH_CODE'],\
calc_interval='1Q',\
start_date_override=x['date']).values
```

Thanks!

Comment: yes you can, `timeout=1000` for example, and be careful when you use Cusip, the bbg api usually requires you to format the cusip differently, i believe it should be something like `bdp("/cusip/143130102", ...)`